# Connect iOS App SAP-SUP through Relay Server

Tags: ios, sup

I´m trying to connect to SAP-SUP trough a relay server and I followed the [How-To: Transitioning Existing Object API Applications to Mobile SDK 2.1 ESD #3](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/40df7004-63a6-2f10-a29a-b626dea85bfa?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&55903294326891) I registered with success the application but I can´t synchronize. I keep getting the error 216 or 219 like this:

```
(MOBILINK_COMMUNICATIONS_ERROR) %1:219 %2: %3:0Details: StreamErrorCode = 219
```

216 stands for - An error occurred while trying to parse an HTTP header. The header may be malformed.

219 stands for - An unexpected character was read in an HTTP header. The header may be malformed or the other side may not be sending HTTP at all.

```
SUPConnectionProfile *sp = [RHDC1RHDC1DB getSynchronizationProfile];

[sp setAsyncReplay:NO];
[sp setUser:kSUPLoginUsername];
[sp setPassword:kSUPLoginPassword];
[sp setServerName:kSUPServerName];
[sp setPortNumber:kSUPServerPort];    
[sp setNetworkProtocol:@"https"];
[sp setNetworkStreamParams:@"trusted_certificates=afaria.xpto.en.cer;compression=zlib;url_suffix=/ias_relay_server/server/rs_server.dll/SUPRBSFarm"];
```

The NetworkStreamParameters seem fine. I can´t find the error on that line!
As anyone successfully connected through a relay server? Or can find the error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that instead of the server configurations:

```
[sp setNetworkStreamParams:@"trusted_certificates=afaria.xpto.en.cer;compression=zlib;url_suffix=/ias_relay_server/server/rs_server.dll/SUPRBSFarm"];
```

i should have used the cliente configurations:

```
[sp setNetworkStreamParams:@"trusted_certificates=afaria.xpto.en.cer;compression=zlib;url_suffix=/ias_relay_server/cliente/rs_client.dll/SUPRBSFarm"];
```

The code errors did not point me in the right direction, but this was the way to solve it.

Comment: need your guidance for App registeration through relay server,i have followed the link u referred to.In that I dint find [app registerApplication:800]; code.......without this code how can you register??

Comment: Sorry. Don´t have an answer for that.

Comment: /ias_relay_server/clientE/rs_client.dll - Do not copy this.